# Use/Access Android and iOS (Mobile) Camera

Tags: javascript, android, ios, camera, android-camera-intent

I make an HTML5-CSS-JS Android (and iOS) Application and i try to get access to the mobile device camera.

I tried two ways to get access to camera and both ways work fine when i use them from a Browser, but when i build my .APK file and i open my App none of them is working the same way as from a Browser:

First 1) I tried Input Tag and when i click to choose/browse it allows me only to select an Existing file NOT to capture or record a new one:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

Then 2) I found (navigator.getUserMedia) this code on web that works also from a browser but when i open my App it seems like no working and not requesting for device hardware access at all:

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
/*****************************************************************/
function init()
{
    if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)
    {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, onSuccess, onFail);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('webRTC not available');
    }
}

function onSuccess(stream)
{
    document.getElementById('camFeed').src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function onFail()
{
    alert('could not connect stream');
}

function takePhoto()
{
    var c = document.getElementById('photo');
    var v = document.getElementById('camFeed');
    c.getContext('2d').drawImage(v, 0, 0, 320, 240);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:352px; height:625px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#fff;" >
    <div>
      <video id="camFeed" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
    </video>
  </div>

    <div>
        <canvas id="photo" width="320" height="240">
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:82px;">
        <input type="button" value="Take Photo" onclick="takePhoto();">
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone has an idea of how can I access camera on Android or iOS? 
I tried it with and without camera permissions but this was not the problem.

Help... Thank you in Advance. (If my question is not clear comment please.)

Comment: Post a minimal but complete example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I edited my question. Do you need more info? Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic code, it will allow you to record/capture the file.

HTML:

```
<input id="reviewVideoCapture" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
```

JS (Using JQuery):

```
var videoFile = $('#reviewVideoCapture').get(0).files[0];
```

Use this if you want to upload the video somewhere:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/photo" method="POST" >
  <input id="reviewVideoCapture" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
  <input id="submitFormButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

Even though this works, I would still not recommend doing it this way.  The results on mobile are buggy and hard to work with.  The better way is to use cordova/ionic.  A good example on how to do this can be found here:
https://github.com/yafraorg/ionictests

Comment: Is this access to video record?

Comment: It does not work from an Android App. It gives me the option to choose only device files. No access to camera. App manage input tag in different way than when you click it from a Browser.

Comment: That is correct.  If you are acutally running on a mobile device, you are going to need a plugin like the ones available from cordova.  You will need to create a cordova/ionic project and add the plugin to it.  The example repo link i posted walks through this whole process.  If the code is too confusing I can create a small project that demos it.  Let me know.

Comment: I already have an app made with NetBeans. Do i have to pass my whole up to another platform to use Cordova plugin (Like Cordova, PhoneGap, Intel XDK and etc) or I can just insert the plugin in my existing project?